# Via in pad without fill/cap

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, via

I am currently designing an HDI-PCB. Outer-layers micro vias, inner layers buried vias.

As cost is of big concern my idea is to not fill and cap (copper plating) vias (100 μm drill ~ 75 μm finished diameter) in 0201 and 0.35 mm pitch BGA pads.

My reasoning is: As the outer prepreg (60 μm) and the copper film (30 μm after plating) are extremely thin (~90 μm) I do hope, that there is no issue in reliable soldering.

As a precaution I did place such a via in every BGA pad (so it does sit "in the pit"), as well as on every 0201 pad (not just a single pad per part were required).

My questions:
How wrong is this assumption?

Are there any suggestions to minimize negative effects and still save the extra cost associated with via filling and plating (low quantities, so rather high PCB costs)?

Do you have any experience with such an approach (assembly yield, etc.)?

Why do I ask:
I have read some articles and posts - these give me headaches. But, as these discussions do mostly focus on ~0.3 mm vias through 1.6 mm PCBs, I am still optimistic.

Comment: Have you asked your intended manufacturer? FWIW its fairly normal IME not to do via-in-pad for BGA pads. Your biggest cost adder is not the capping but the blind and burried vias

Comment: The added area needed to get rid of buried/blind vias will likely cost less than keeping things tight and using buried/blind vias. If you can avoid buried/blind vias, do so. Some products require the high density, so you may have no choice, but for prototypes and so on - buried/blind vias are a luxury unless you're prototyping the final layout - not always the best idea.

Comment: @crasic Hmmm BGA is 0.35 Pitch with 90/90um Track/spacing on outer Layer. It is only a 4x4 (16WLP) device - but routing without Via-In-Pad is out of question.

Comment: I am probably overloading a term. What I mean is that the forgoing the fill-and-cap process for vias in pad is on tight BGA breakout is typical in my experience.  There are manufacturing process concerns e.g thermal conductivity and solder-ability. They are not insurmountable, recommend to engage the manufacturer early in your process.  At the end of the day, you can imagine whatever design rules you would like,  and the question is if it represents the capabilities of a real world manufacturing process. There is nothing inherently wrong with a via in pad that is not capped.

Comment: Also, keep in mind with small quantities it is much easier to QA or hand-pick the best production articles, question is if the potential reduction in yield and chance of scrapping a board exceeds the cost of simply going with the more reliable process, assuming it is more reliable, which would be up to the QA expert of the manufacturer to confirm, or someone with equivalent process know-how on your team.